# New Teams Privilege links to current site

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

[image]

The link in the Achievements dropdown for the new "Access to content health" privilege rather thoughtfully points me at https://currentsite.stackexchange.com/c/teamname/content-health.

Unfortunately only Stack Overflow has teams so... it basically 404s if you're on any other site at the time and click on the link.

This probably should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

We should now be suppressing this notification when not on a private Team.