# Error when trying to visit Content Health queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, stack-overflow-for-teams

When I go to https://stackoverflow.com/c/teamname/content-health I get this:

[image: oops something bad happened]

I found a Content Health review in the timeline, clicked, then clicked on this link, which was labeled "Back to Team Name Content Health". I do not have any privileges on the team, and this queue unlocks at 75 but I think I should be able to view it anyway.

I think it's the wrong link here. The correct one is https://stackoverflow.com/c/teamname/review/content-health with "review" in the url. This one works for me, and I see a message saying I need more rep.  (But also wrong links shouldn't give you an error.)

Comment: Probably related: [New Teams Privilege links to current site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413186/new-teams-privilege-links-to-current-site)

Comment: It's the same queue but I'm inside the team when I click the link.